# Taking hit from Plague Zombie

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

The Plague Zombie card says:

If undefeated, banish the Plague Zombie, and each character at this location must succeed at a Constitution or Fortitude 6 check or be dealt 1d4 Acid damage.

This means: if it was me who encountered this card and had not defeated it, I would have to take the usual combat damage and after that execute the "if undefeated" text or just the "if undefeated" text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You'll take damage and then trigger the "if undefeated" effect**

This is covered under the **Encountering A Card** section on page 10 of the rulebook where it outlines the specific steps to resolve an encounter, and under the **Attempting A Check** section on pages 10-12 which details out one of those steps with several sub-steps.

The steps to resolve an encounter are:

> Evade the Card (Optional)
>   Apply Any Effects That Happen Before The Encounter, If Needed
>   *Attempt the Check*
>   Attempt the Next Check, If Needed
>   Apply Any Effects That Happen After The Encounter, If Needed
>   *Resolve the Encounter*

When you get to the Attempt the Check step, you follow these sub-steps:

> Determine Which Die You're Using
>   Determine the Difficulty
>   Play Cards and Use Powers That Affect the Check (Optional)
>   Assemble Your Dice
>   Attempt the Roll
>   *Take Damage, If Necessary*

So you'll take the damage from failing to defeat the Plague Zombie first during the *Attempt the Check* step's *Take Damage, If Necessary* sub-step. Then, during the *Resolve the Encounter* step, you have not "succeeded at all of the checks required to defeat a bane", so it is *undefeated*, triggering the special effect on the card.